# jersey-spring3 Bridge Isn't Finding My Resources

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0

I'm using the Jersey / Spring bridge (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) and I can't get it to see my Jersey resources via a Spring XML config file.

(Spring 3.2, Jersey 2.5, jersey-spring3 2.5, jackson-jaxrs-json-provider 2.2.3.)

In my Spring config file I have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json, com.mycompany.mappers, com.mycompany.resources" />
```

`SpringComponentProvider.initialize()` succeeds, and `SpringComponentProvider.bind` gets called for a bunch of classes (well, actually just the stuff in the Jersey server's WADL package), but is *not* called for my resource classes.

I can see that Spring is finding my resource:

```
2013-12-30 16:47:24,246 [main]  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry:215  DEBUG   Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'myResource'
2013-12-30 16:47:24,246 [main]  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory:432    DEBUG   Creating instance of bean 'myResource'
```

The sample app referenced in the docs (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.5/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp) defines a Jersey application subclass of `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` and programmatically registers resources. I was hoping to use a Spring XML config file to bind resources, rather than hardcoding them. (This used to work in Jersey 1.x.)

How can I get Jersey 2 to recognize my resources?

Comment: Could you post the relevant sections of your web.xml please. Specifically the Jersey Servlet Container definition stuff, and init-params. I'm assuming that you get 404 when you try to access your Jersey endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

The answer is that the Spring bridge for Jersey 2 doesn't support `<context:component-scan .../>` and you have to register your resources programmatically.

Have a look at the Jersey/Spring docs (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) and follow the Spring sample app exactly (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp)... if you step off that path then it won't work.

The key part is to subclass `ResourceConfig` (e.g. https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/spring/MyApplication.java) like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication () {
        register(MyRequestContextFilter.class);
        register(MyResource.class);
        packages("com.mycompany.resources");
        ...
    }
}
```

You then name your subclass in your app descriptor using `javax.ws.rs.Application` (e.g. https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.spring.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```